# How to correct my nginx configuration if it is wrong?

Tags: nginx, redirect, configuration, proxypass

I am new to nginx. I try to learn using search www and stackoverflow. Mostly I get help to understand how to build my nginx configuration.

I have my domain as www.mysite.com. Everything; **landing page**, the **error** and **server error** must be **redirect** to default index.html. I also define my access and error log. All this done (below code) inside the /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.

I need to redirect (**proxy_pass**) **/admin**, **/user** and anything related to them. Example the /admin has also different folder like /admin/login/. I need to everything after /admin must be redirected. The same goes also for the /user as well.

**1)** Looking at my code am I redirect the **location /admin** and **location /user** correctly?

**2)** I also use try_files $uri $uri/ =404; in redirection. which also redirects the 404 to default index.html. Am I doing right?

**3)** I am also denying access to some file and folder. Am I doing right?

My main question is How to correct my nginx configuration if it is wrong? So to understand the correct nginx configuration I divide my question to 3 different question above. I hope I didnt brake stackoverflow how to ask question guidelines.

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

```
server {
    charset UTF-8;
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name www.mysite.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/host.error.log  main;

    # define a root location variable and assign a value
    set $rootLocation /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # define www.mysite.com landing page to the static index.html page
    location / {
        root   rootLocation;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    # define error page to the static index.html page
    error_page 404  /index.html;
    location = /index.html {
        root rootLocation;
        internal;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static index.html page
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /index.html;
    location = /index.html {
        root   rootLocation;
        internal;
    }

    # redirect www.mysite.com/admin to localhost
    # /admin or /admin/ or /admin/**** must be redirect to localhost
    location /admin {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:3000";
    }

    # redirect www.mysite.com/user to localhost
    # /user or /user/ or /user/**** must be redirect to localhost   
    location /user {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:3001";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usual to place the `root` statement once in the `server` block, rather than repeat the same value in multiple `location` blocks.

---

You are using `proxy_pass` to change the URI before passing it upstream. In this case, the `location` value and the URI part of the `proxy_pass` value should either both end with `/` or neither end with `/`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

Usually you do **not** want to place `try_files` and `proxy_pass` in the same `location`. This causes Nginx to check for the existence of the file in its document root before allowing the request to pass upstream.

---

You should not need to deny access to the configuration files, as these file should not be within the document root in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Richard. First how to define root in 1 place and use other places? Secondly I newer undurstand the proxy_pass. Nginx and the localhost/3000 or 3001 it is in the same machine. Where I define the try_files?

Comment: In my example the /admin means anything related to /admin such as /admin or /admin=***** or /admin/login. So is my configuration /admin is correct or should I change it to /admin/*

Comment: The value of `root` is inherited from the outer block unless you redefine it within the `location` block. You do not need the `try_files` statement in the `location /admin/` or `location /user/` blocks. The statement `location /admin/` means any URI that begins with `/admin/` (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details).

Comment: Thanks Richard I update my code. Only part that cant get it is the proxy_pass. (sorry for my English). the link you provide talks about "....original request URI...". In my case if uri maches ( /admin ) I need to past that uri and not to changed URI as it shows in my example. If my uri is (ex /admin=?123 or /admin/login/1 ) does nginx redirects my uri using proxy_pass correctly?

Comment: The `proxy_pass` statements in your question include a URI part which is `/`. That causes Nginx to modify the requested URI and remove `admin` or `user` from the original request. If you want to pass the entire URI upstream without modification, remove the trailing `/` from the `proxy_pass` statement.

Comment: I update my question with your help. Thank you very much Richard.